# How to add more tags when using Instagram API?

Tags: php, instagram

How can I search for multiple tags using the Instagram endpoint `/tags/tag-name/media/recent`? For example, instead of just searching for one tag like "snow", I would like to search for multiple tags, maybe "snow" and "snowman".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Instagram endpoint for searching by tags only supports single tags. You would need to handle searching for multiple tags yourself and combine the results on your end.